# How to use WMIC to connect to remote machine and output OS information to a file?

Tags: wmi, query

I want to know how to use WMIC to connect to remote host and output their PC's OS information(Installed programs list) to a file.

I tried

```
wmic /node: <IP address> OS get vendor, name > c:\output.txt
```

but i got error `"Node - <IP> Error: Description = Invalid query"`

But Actually, i think i need to be domain administrator for permission.
so i tried

```
wmic /node: <IP> /domain: <domain.inc> /user:administrator /password:<password> OS get vendor, name > c:\output.txt
```

I got error: `Invalid Global switch.`

I want to get all of PC's OS information( installed programs list) by using WMIC. (i think i need to access with domain administrator cause all of PC is joined with domain) and im an administrator

Please...help me ㅠ____ㅠ ah, it seems to be ok when i tried with just my PC.

```
WMIC /output:C:\%computername%.txt product get name, vendor, version
```

WMIC OS get name, vendor, version >> C:\%computername%.txt

if i did like above, it is ok to get txt file. but i want to remote all PC and get an information file...@_@~~~~

one more question>> is it connected with Security policy or Group policy something? or Firewall something..........@_@;;

Answer (score 11):

`os get vendor` - there is no such thing as an OS vendor, that's where the `invalid query` is coming from. See the available properties - there's a Version, but no Vendor:

```
C:\>wmic os get /?

Property get operations.
USAGE:

GET [<property list>] [<get switches>]
NOTE: <property list> ::= <property name> | <property name>,  <property list>

The following properties are available:
Property                                Type                    Operation
========                                ====                    =========
BootDevice                              N/A                     N/A
BuildNumber                             N/A                     N/A
BuildType                               N/A                     N/A
CSDVersion                              N/A                     N/A
CSName                                  N/A                     N/A
CodeSet                                 N/A                     N/A
CountryCode                             N/A                     N/A
CurrentTimeZone                         N/A                     N/A
Debug                                   N/A                     N/A
Description                             N/A                     N/A
Distributed                             N/A                     N/A
EncryptionLevel                         N/A                     N/A
ForegroundApplicationBoost              N/A                     N/A
FreePhysicalMemory                      N/A                     N/A
FreeSpaceInPagingFiles                  N/A                     N/A
FreeVirtualMemory                       N/A                     N/A
InstallDate                             N/A                     N/A
LastBootUpTime                          N/A                     N/A
LocalDateTime                           N/A                     N/A
Locale                                  N/A                     N/A
Manufacturer                            N/A                     N/A
MaxNumberOfProcesses                    N/A                     N/A
MaxProcessMemorySize                    N/A                     N/A
Name                                    N/A                     N/A
NumberOfLicensedUsers                   N/A                     N/A
NumberOfProcesses                       N/A                     N/A
NumberOfUsers                           N/A                     N/A
OSLanguage                              N/A                     N/A
OSProductSuite                          N/A                     N/A
OSType                                  N/A                     N/A
Organization                            N/A                     N/A
OtherTypeDescription                    N/A                     N/A
PlusProductID                           N/A                     N/A
PlusVersionNumber                       N/A                     N/A
Primary                                 N/A                     N/A
QuantumLength                           N/A                     N/A
QuantumType                             N/A                     N/A
RegisteredUser                          N/A                     N/A
SerialNumber                            N/A                     N/A
ServicePackMajorVersion                 N/A                     N/A
ServicePackMinorVersion                 N/A                     N/A
SizeStoredInPagingFiles                 N/A                     N/A
Status                                  N/A                     N/A
SystemDevice                            N/A                     N/A
SystemDirectory                         N/A                     N/A
SystemDrive                             N/A                     N/A
TotalSwapSpaceSize                      N/A                     N/A
TotalVirtualMemorySize                  N/A                     N/A
TotalVisibleMemorySize                  N/A                     N/A
Version                                 N/A                     N/A
WindowsDirectory                        N/A                     N/A
```

And there is no `/DOMAIN` option in wmic either.

```
C:\>wmic /?

[global switches] <command>

The following global switches are available:
/NAMESPACE           Path for the namespace the alias operate against.
/ROLE                Path for the role containing the alias definitions.
/NODE                Servers the alias will operate against.
/IMPLEVEL            Client impersonation level.
/AUTHLEVEL           Client authentication level.
/LOCALE              Language id the client should use.
/PRIVILEGES          Enable or disable all privileges.
/TRACE               Outputs debugging information to stderr.
/RECORD              Logs all input commands and output.
/INTERACTIVE         Sets or resets the interactive mode.
/FAILFAST            Sets or resets the FailFast mode.
/USER                User to be used during the session.
/PASSWORD            Password to be used for session login.
/OUTPUT              Specifies the mode for output redirection.
/APPEND              Specifies the mode for output redirection.
/AGGREGATE           Sets or resets aggregate mode.
/AUTHORITY           Specifies the <authority type> for the connection.
/?[:<BRIEF|FULL>]    Usage information.
```

You could try:

```
wmic /NODE:"servername" /USER:"yourdomain\administrator" OS GET Name
```

It will prompt for your password.

Comment: Thank you. i totally didnt know about this..@_@;;; thank you for your help. now i know how to do ! ! !